# What R-package can produce this plot?

Tags: r, plot

I want to produce the graphics illustrated in "B" and "C". Do you know what the name of the plot is and what R-package I can use to produce it from my own data?

[image]

Comment: just add the `horiz=TRUE` parameter to a regular bar plot. see documentation [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html).

Comment: They're just bar charts with flipped coordinates. If you're using `ggplot2` add `coord_flip()`: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding this again as an answer.
this is simple to accomplish with regular barplot.
see example as shown [here](https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html)

```
counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", horiz=TRUE,
names.arg=c("3 Gears", "4 Gears", "5 Gears"))
```